# How to Merge guest quote items to customer quote(if customer log in) by magento 2 rest API

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, rest-api

If any one is add products in cart by guest and after that login then how it will merge guest cart to customer login cart items by Rest API.
if anyone found this solutions, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using following api endpoint

```
Method - PUT 
{URL}/rest/V1/guest-carts/{guest-card-id} 
Param - { 
  "customerId": 3, 
  "storeId": 1 
} 
Authorization -"Bearer {user-token}"
```

There is also a known issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24808. It will be fixed in Magento 2.3.4.

I created an extension to fix this issue for the Magento version < 2.3.4. https://github.com/troublediehard/plab-cartsmergefix